# Trying to serve wordpress in a subdirectory using NGINX webserver but failing

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a react website which I am serving using NGINX. I wanted to create a blog for the same. So I tried to use wordpress in a sub-directory.

```
`
server {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name domain.com;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
         location ^~ /blog {
                   client_max_body_size 10m;
        
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
                }

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/wordpress(/.+\.php)(.*)$;
                          include fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                        include fastcgi_params;



                }
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 
    #ssl certificates here

}
`
```

After hours of reading docs, blogs and stack I got my homepage set up. However all my pages on the blog are returning 404. I am attaching my nginx config.

My directory structure is

/var/www/html/ : root folder for my react website

/var/www/html/blog : root folder for my wordpress ( no /wordpress subfolder present)

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. I get "no input file specified" error